# Login Problem after changing some settings

Tags: login, auto-login

I have done some operations at the same time as follows:

1. Created a new general account.
2. Changed the password of super user to empty.
3. Set auto login for super user.

After restarting my system, I am facing following problems:

- I am not able to login through my super user, it come back to same welcome screen.
- I am able to login with general user, but in that account I am not able to login through Super User.

How can I correct this?

Comment: 1. Shouldn't cause any problem///2.Shouldn't have done that///3. Shouldn't have done that either. You're not suppose to log in with root.

Comment: You can just log in with *Your* account open a terminal and do `sudo -i`

Answer (score 0):

root is not designed for auto login, it was designed for password login.  Remove auto login for root, and this should resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Root account is not for logging in. You can gain super user privileges by using `sudo`, `gksu` or `su root`. You shouldn't play with your system  like this unless you are pro user. Changing root, wheel, /etc/sudoers or any similar thing without proper knowledge may break your system and it'll be hard to repair it.

Also, root account without password is like big label "viruses and hackers come here".

Try to restore everything to a previous state. If you can't... well... maybe we can fix it, but we'll need more info. Propably you'll have to use rescue mode or live system.